# Snakemake error "Not all output, log and benchmark files of rule <RULE> contain the same wildcards

Tags: wildcard, snakemake

I have a barebone snake file as follows as a test/demo, but it kept on producing errors:

```
Not all output, log and benchmark files of rule test contain the same wildcards.
```

Here is the snakefile content:

```
samples = ['A', 'B', 'C']

rule test:
    input:
        "mapped/{sample_name}.fsa", sample_name=samples
    output:
        "mapped/{sample_name}_out.fsa", sample_name=samples
    shell: "cp {input} {output}"
```

Cannot for the life of me figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I should not have used the samples list in this way. Removing sample_name=samples from this rule and adding a new rule with expand function solved it.
Sorry about the trouble.

```
samples = ['A', 'B', 'C']

rule all:
    input: expand("mapped/{sample_name}.fsa", sample_name=samples)

rule test:
    input:
        "mapped/{sample_name}.fsa"
    output:
        "mapped/{sample_name}_out.fsa"
    shell: "cp {input} {output}"
```